# How to use encrypted connection with MySQL on Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, openssl

I'm struggling to get a Dockerised MySQL instance to support SSL.

The service in my docker-compose file looks like this:

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --ssl-ca=/etc/ssl/mysql/ca.pem --ssl-cert=/etc/ssl/mysql/server-cert.pem --ssl-key=/etc/ssl/mysql/server-key.pem
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${MYSQL_USER}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
    volumes:
      - "./data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./config/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/ssl.cnf"
      - "./config/mysql/certs:/etc/ssl/mysql"
```

When I start up the stack I get these errors from the MySQL container:

```
[ERROR] SSL error: Unable to get private key from '/etc/ssl/mysql/server-key.pem'
[Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: Unable to get private key
```

I've tried to chown the key from `root` to `mysql` and then bring up the stack again, but that doesn't seem to work.

I generated the key files from the commands at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html, like this:

```
# Create server certificate, remove passphrase, and sign it
# server-cert.pem = public key, server-key.pem = private key
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3600 \
        -nodes -keyout server-key.pem -out server-req.pem
openssl rsa -in server-key.pem -out server-key.pem
openssl x509 -req -in server-req.pem -days 3600 \
        -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out server-cert.pem
```

The files on the host have the following permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 andrew andrew 4096 Dec 11 10:25 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 andrew andrew 4096 Dec 10 19:27 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1    999 docker 1675 Dec 10 19:20 ca-key.pem
-rw-rw-r-- 1    999 docker 1294 Dec 10 19:20 ca.pem
-rw-rw-r-- 1    999 docker 1123 Dec 10 19:20 client-cert.pem
-rw-rw-r-- 1    999 docker 1679 Dec 10 19:20 client-key.pem
-rw-rw-r-- 1    999 docker  989 Dec 10 19:20 client-req.pem
-rw-rw-r-- 1    999 docker 1127 Dec 10 19:20 server-cert.pem
-rw------- 1    999 docker 1675 Dec 11 10:25 server.key
-rw-rw-r-- 1    999 docker 1704 Dec 11 09:43 server-key.pem
-rw-rw-r-- 1    999 docker  956 Dec 11 09:43 server-req.pem
```

This happens if I manually generate the certificates and mount them as a volume, or if I run a shell on the container and run the command `mysql_ssl_rsa_setup --datadir=/etc/ssl/mysql --verbose` (after clearing out the certificates that I created).  In other words when I run `openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem server-cert.pem client-cert.pem` I see that both certificates are "OK" (no matter which way I generate them).

Why can't MySQL find the private key from that file?

Comment: Your mysql user is the same inside the container ? By default uid/gid is 999

Comment: I haven't changed it in the container.  I don't have a mysql user on my host.

Comment: What are the rights on this file and corresponding folders (from host) ?

Comment: I've amended the question, I think I can see where you're going with this... the mysql user can't read them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems.

When I generated the certificate it had the wrong permissions.  Running `chown 999:docker` on the certificates helps let MySQL read it in the container.  When I was using the MySQL tool to generate certificates I was skipping this step.

The second problem was that the common name (CN) of the CA certificate needs to be different from the CN of the server certificate.

In the section where it gives the commands to generate the certificates, the MySQL manual says:

> To generate test files, you can press Enter to all prompts. To
>   generate files for production use, you should provide nonempty
>   responses.

But a little higher on the page it has a warning about the CN needing to be different.